# KMDF driver fails to build VS 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, kmdf, wdf

I'm trying to build and compile the device driver example given in MSDN website https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/writing-a-very-small-kmdf--driver, however build operation failed without any errors. after increasing the verbosity of build operations I get the following:

> Using "DPVerifierTask" task from assembly "E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\build\bin\Microsoft.DriverKit.Build.Tasks.PackageVerifier.15.0.dll".
>     Task "DPVerifierTask"
>     Done executing task "DPVerifierTask" -- FAILED.
>   Done building project "Driver.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
>   Time Elapsed 00:00:00.09
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
>   ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Thanks in advance